# Class' Struct's function declaration in header and definition in cpp. lnk2019 when using function in separate lib

Tags: c++, struct, translation-unit

The following will build fine. When I try to use a function in a different library I get linker errors.

```
OtherClass.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: float __cdecl myClass::myClassStruct::myConvoludedFunction(int,int)" (?myConvoludedFunction@myClassStruct@myClass@@QEAAMHH_N@Z) referenced in function "public: __cdecl myNamespace::OtherClass::OtherClassFunc(class myNamespace::Something &)" (??0OtherClass@myNamespace@@QEAA@AEAVDtDe@1@@Z)
```

Header:

```
   class MY_EXPORT_MACRO myClass
   {
    public:
        myClass();
        ~myClass();
        struct myClassStruct
        {
            int var1
            int var2
            float myConvoludedFunction(int,int);
        }
    }
```

cpp

```
#include "myClass.h"
myClass::myClass()
{
    //something initialisy
}

myClass::~myClass()
{
    //something destructiony
}

float myClass::myClassStruct::myConvoludedFunction(int a, int b)
{
    //Something convoluded and secret
    return 0;

}
```

In the actual code there is a number of structs defined in the class. So I tried making them all nested classes with public members and member functions. Similar thing: lib builds, lnk2019 when using the functions in a separate lib. The other functions in myClass work fine.

It's being used like this:

```
#include myClass.h
namespace myNameSpace
{
    OtherClass::OtherClassFunc(Something & athing)
    {
        myClass * object = new myClass();

        myClass::myClassStruct aStruct;

        FunctionThatInitialisesStruct( aStruct);

        aStruct.someConvoludedFunction(1,2);

    }
}
```

Is there something I'm doing that's obviously wrong? Is it not standard to have struct function definitions declared separately?

Comment: hurpdurp typo in the question. I renamed removed a lot of the code i'm working with. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to export/import the symbols for `myClassStruct` also.

Use:

```
struct MY_EXPORT_MACRO myClassStruct { ... };
```

Comment: Even if the struct is declared inside an exported class?
It compiles now. Still don't know why it needs struct export macro if its declared inside an exported class. I thought that meant everything in the class was exported.

Comment: Yes. A class may not want users of the DLL to use its nested classes if the nested class is an implementation detail.

Comment: Interesting. The more you know.
So what else isn't exported in an exported class?

Comment: All member variables and member functions are exported. If memory serves me right, only nested classes are not exported.